# Slow Docker build image - Sending context is very slow

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

when I build a docker image from a docker-compose with "context" configured, it need a lot of time to complete.
The step that keep too much time is "Sending context...": it need 20 minutes for a 85MB folder.

The issue appear both in Ubuntu 20.04 and MacOS (using colima as virualization engine).

The folder I need to send is a nodejs project, so it has a lot of small files in the node_modules folder, but I can not excclude it becouse I need to run the node project in the container.

Is there a way to speed up the Sending context step?

Comment: Typical Node Dockerfiles `RUN npm ci` or something similar to rebuild the `node_modules` directory, and you'd usually include it in your `.dockerignore` file to exclude it from the build context.  (There's especially a potential problem reusing `node_modules` from a MacOS host in a Linux container.)

Comment: You are right, it's safer if nom re-install packages in the build. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution: from docker-compose 1.25.1, docker support the BuildKit, a different way to build the image that solve this issue.

You only need to update the docker-compose and set this variable:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
```

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/